# Compute eigenvector using given eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I have a fairly small matrix (cca 100x100). I have computed first four largest eigenvalues (with modified Lanczsos and Lanczsos with reorthogonalization).
I know this might be a rather dumb question, but I can't find a way to compute corresponding eigenvector in Matlab. Sure I remember, how to calculate it by hand:
Calculate kernel of matrix $(A - \lambda I)$ and you get corresponding eigenvector.

So, is there any "easy" way to get this done in Matlab?

Comment: Matlab has a "null" function which returns an orthonormal basis for the nullspace iirc. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Mathlab can solve systems of equations, and the Kernel of that matrix is the solution to the homogeneous system of equations.

Comment: x =  (A-$\lambda$ I)\zeros(cca100,1)? Easy, but there should be more effective ways od doing this.

Comment: $x = (A - \lambda I)$\zeros(100,1) doesn't work... it just returns zero vector...

Comment: You can add an equation $x_1 = 1$  (Additional row in A-$\lambda$ I).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration seems to be the answer I was looking for. Thanks folks.

Comment: I think @Antoine means `ones` not `zeros`, no?

Comment: Why not just use `eigs()`?

Comment: Because I specifically wanted eigenvalues obtained by Lanczos algorithm. Like I said, inverse iteration does the trick. And moreover, it converges in only 3-5 steps to $10^{-15}$